# can not mock jsx/tsx in jest

Tags: next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have next js, jest, react testing library.
The problem is that i can not mock component, when i do

```
jest.mock('ui/forms/Field/Field', () => {
    const original = jest.requireActual('ui/forms/Field/Field');
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...original,
        Field: (props: any) => <div ref={props.inputRef}></div>,
    };
});
```

it calls error P**roperty declarations[0] of VariableDeclaration expected node to be of a type ["VariableDeclarator"] but instead got undefined**

jest.config

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    // on node 14.x coverage provider v8 offers good speed and more or less good report
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/templates/ui/forms/**/*{.tsx,.jsx}'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
        // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
        '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

        // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
        '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/jest/mocks/style.js',

        // Handle image imports
        // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
        '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': `<rootDir>/jest/mocks/file.js`,

        // Handle module aliases
        '^templates/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/templates/$1',
        '^scripts/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/scripts/$1',
        '^ui/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/templates/ui/$1',
    },
    // Add more setup options before each test is run
    // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
        // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$'],
};
```

i tried to change transform block in jest.config